# Prologs returns in haskell

Tags: haskell, prolog

I'm rewritting my Prolog program in Haskell and i have small problem, how can i do something like that

```
myFunc(Field, Acc, Acc) :- 
    % some "ending" condition
    !.
myFunc(Field, Acc, Result) :-
    nextField(Field, Field2),
    test1(Field2,...),
    myFunc(Field2, Acc, Result).
myFunc(Field, Acc, Result) :-
    nextField(Field, Field2),
    test2(Ak, (X1, Y1)),
    myFunc(Field2, [Field2|Acc], Result).
```

in Haskell? Code above is checking some condition and recursivly calls itself so in the end i get list of specific fields. The whole point is that if some condition (test1 or test2) fails, it is returning to the last point it could make other choice and does it. How do i implement something like that in Haskell?

Comment: simulate with a stack ?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you detailed the algorithm you are tried to recreate in a little more detail. I know little no prolog as of yet. Is there an input data structure you are recursing over? It sounds like you should be using the list monad and guard from Control.Monad, but I can not say for sure with out more details.

Comment: @Davorak - i have list of fields as an input and i need a list of deleted fields as a result. There are some conditions that determine whenever i can leave/delete field and those are test1 and test2 (i'm leaving field in first case of myFunc and deleting in second). In general, as a result i need list of all solutions meeting my conditions, and one solution is one list of deleted fields. In prolog i was returning one solution at a time and then i was searching for another one by hitting ";" but i guess that in haskell i have to find them all at once. I hope it clarifies some doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To model Prolog computations as expressively in Haskell, you need a backtracking monad. This is trivially done using the `LogicT` monad. Your example as it stands translates to the following:

```
import Control.Monad.Logic

myFunc :: Int -> [Int] -> Logic [Int]
myFunc field acc = ifte (exitCond field acc) (\_-> return acc) $         
    (do f <- nextField field
        guard $ test1 f 
        myFunc f acc)
    `mplus`
    (do f <- nextField field
        guard $ test2 f 
        myFunc f (f:acc))
```

Assuming the following implementations for the functions and predicates:

```
nextField i = return (i+1)
test1 f = f < 10
test2 f = f < 20
exitCond f a = guard (f > 15)
```

You use `mplus` to combine to `Logic` computations so that if one fails it backtracks and tries the other one. `ifte` is just a soft cut (there's no hard cut in `logict`, although I believe it's trivial to implement since `logict` is based on continuations) to exit when the exiting condition is true. You run your computation as follows:

```
Main> runLogic (myFunc 1 []) (\a r -> a:r) []
[[16,15,14,13,12,11,10],[16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9],[16,15,14,13,12,11,10,8]...
```

`runLogic` takes the `Logic` computation, a continuation and an initial value for the output of the continuation. Here I just passed a continuation which will accumulate all results in a list. The above will backtrack and get all solutions, unlike the Prolog example, since we used a soft cut instead of a hard cut. To stop backtracking after getting the first solution you can use `once`:

```
Main> runLogic (once $ myFunc 1 []) (\a r -> a:r) []
[[16,15,14,13,12,11,10]]
```

you can also use `observe` to observe the first solution only, without having to pass a continuation:

```
Main> observe (myFunc 1 [])
[16,15,14,13,12,11,10]
```

or even `obserMany` and `observeAll`:

```
observeMany 5 (myFunc 1 []) --returns the first 5 solutions

observerAll (myFunc 1 [])   --returns a list of all solutions
```

Finally, you will need to install the `logict` package to get the above code to work. Use `cabal install logict` to install it.

### **Edit: Answering your question in the comments**

Yes, you can do something similar without having to install `logict`. Although a dedicated backtracking monad makes things less complicated and makes clear what you are trying to do.

To model the `logict` example above you only need the `[]` monad

```
myFunc :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
myFunc field acc | exitCond field acc = return acc
myFunc field acc = do
     let m1 = do
           f <- nextField field
           guard $ test1 f
           myFunc f acc
         m2 = do
           f <- nextField field
           guard $ test2 f
           myFunc f (f:acc)
      in m1 `mplus` m2

nextField i = return $ i + 1
exitCond i a = i > 15
test1 i = i < 10
test2 i = i < 20
```

You can run it as follows:

```
Main> myFunc 1 []
[[16,15,14,13,12,11,10],[16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9],[16,15,14,13,12,11,10,8]...
```

You can also choose how many solutions you want as before:

```
Main> head $ myFunc 1 []
[16,15,14,13,12,11,10]
Main> take 3 $ myFunc 1 []
[[16,15,14,13,12,11,10],[16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9],[16,15,14,13,12,11,10,8]]
```

However, you will need the `Cont` monad, and thus the `ListT` monad, to implement a hard cut as in the Prolog example, which was not available in the `logict` example above:

```
import Control.Monad.Cont
import Control.Monad.Trans.List

myFunc :: Int -> ListT (Cont [[Int]]) [Int]
myFunc field = callCC $ \exit -> do
    let g field acc | exitCond field acc = exit acc
        g field acc =
          let m1 = do
                     f <- nextField field
                     guard $ test1 f
                     g f acc 
              m2 = do
                     f <- nextField field
                     guard $ test2 f
                     g f (f:acc)
          in m1 `mplus` m2
    g field []
```

Like Prolog, this last example will not backtrack again after `exitCond` is satisfied:

```
*Main> runCont (runListT (myFunc 1)) id
[[16,15,14,13,12,11,10]]
```

Comment: Just what I need but, I don't really have possibility to install additional packages. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You comment helped clarify some, but there is still some question in mind about what you are looking for so here is an example of using the list monad and guard.

```
import Control.Monad

myFunc lst = do
  e <- lst
  guard $ even e -- only allow even elements
  guard . not $ e `elem` [4,6,8] -- do not allow 4, 6, or 8
  return e -- accumulate results
```

used in ghci:

```
> myFunc [1..20]
[2,10,12,14,16,18,20]
```

Comment: I will give an example. Lets say that i have matrix [[1,2],[1,2]] as an input, I transform it to the list of coorinates: [(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)]. Lets say test1 is that two values can't be the same in single row or column and test 2 is that two deleted field can't be placed next to each other (in row or column). So acceptable solutions are [(0,0),(1,1)] and [(1,0),(0,1)] (coordinates of deleted fields). Now, how prolog is doing it: test1 is fulfilled for first and second coordinates but for third it's not, so prolog is returning to seconds one and "deletes" it, than it continues.

Comment: It is not clear to me how your algorithm is working. For example: "so prolog is returning to seconds one and "deletes" it," you have not specified why it would backtrack here rather then delete the third element, which also then satisfies test one.

Comment: well, yeah, that was actually wrong, sorry for that. It will leave first two, then, test1 will be not fulfilled for third one so it deletes it. But then again test1 will be not fulfilled for fourth one, so it will try to delete it but then test2 will return false, and now it will return to second field and delete it. In the end we will get [(1,0),(0,1)].

Answer (score 0):

I've never programmed in Haskell - then I would call for your help - but could hint about

that Prolog fragment - where I think you have a typo - should be `myFunc(Field2, [(X1,Y1)|Acc], Result).` could be compiled -by hand - in a continuation passing schema.

Let's [google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=haskell%20continuation%20passing%20prolog&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) about it (haskell continuation passing prolog). I will peek first the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation): near Haskell we find the [continuation monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.0.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Cont.html).

Now we can try to translate that Prolog in executable Haskell. Do this make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

Textual translation of your code to Haskell is:

```
myFunc field acc = take 1 $              -- a cut
                     g field acc
  where
    g f a | ending_condition_holds = [a]
    g f a =
      ( nextField f       >>= (\f2 ->
        (if test1  ...                   -- test1 a predicate function
          then  [()]
          else  []  )     >>= (_ ->
        g f2 a         )))
      ++
      ( nextField f       >>= (\f2 ->
        test2  ...        >>= (\_ ->     -- test2 producing some results
        g f2 (f2:a)    )))
```